# Set dynamic url to a href in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to set dynamic links to a href link. What i exactly need to do is to call a js method which returns the url according to domain inside the  a href.

```
 <a href="javascript:getAuthUrl()"><u>Login&gt;&gt;</u></a>

 function getAuthUrl() {
       ...
            if (domain.includes("localhost")) {
                return buildOAuthUrl(hostConfig.dev);
            }
            else if (domain.includes("...")) {
                return buildOAuthUrl(hostConfig.test);
            }
            else if (domain.includes("....")) {
                return buildOAuthUrl(hostConfig.uat);
            }
            else if (domain.includes("....")) {
                return buildOAuthUrl(hostConfig.prod);
            }
            else if (domain.includes("....")) {
                return buildOAuthUrl(hostConfig.test);
            }
            else {
                return buildOAuthUrl(hostConfig.dev);
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried some examples in stackoverflow but that didn't solve my error/problem.

Comment: what error that you got? can you elaborate more

Comment: Could you please add complete code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although 'CertainPerformance' has answered it well. Adding another version incase you want to have it in line with question.

You can use DOM manipulation with anchor tags onClick event directly.

Example:

```
function getAuthUrl() {
    url="";
    if (domain.includes("localhost")) {
        url=buildOAuthUrl("dev");
    }
    else if (domain.includes("...")) {
        url=buildOAuthUrl("test");
    }
    else if (domain.includes("....")) {
        url=buildOAuthUrl("uat");
    }
    var b = document.querySelector("#url");
    b.setAttribute("href", url);    
}

<a id="url" href="" onclick="getAuthUrl()"><u>Login&gt;&gt;</u></a>
```

Comment: Using ".onclick", ".onchange", or "on" anything is bad practice and results in poorly factored, hard-to-manage code; as well as limiting you to one event listener per event. Consider attaching your events with addEventListener, instead, eg: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an event listener instead of using inline eval:

```js
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (Math.random() < 0.5) e.target.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49605314/set-dynamic-url-to-a-href-in-javascript/49605338';
  else e.target.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
});
```

```html
<a>go somewhere</a>
```

(make sure not to use `e.preventDefault()` if you want to preserve the ordinary link-click handling)

Comment: It's just an example - of course on the real page he should somehow select the particular `a` he wants to change and add the listener to that (but I don't know how his HTML is set up)